# How do you find Fourier Transform of a non-integrable function?

Tags: signal-processing, fourier-transform

How do you find a Fourier Transform for a non-integrable function?

For $$\frac{\sin(4x)}{\pi x}$$

According to https://owlcation.com/stem/How-to-Integrate-sinxx-and-cosxx the function is not integrable.

Comment: @user1952009 I've actually enjoyed communicating with you in the past and I have seen that you have a strong command of analysis.  That is a sincere compliment regarding your "math IQ."  But in this case, you've said some very condescending things that began with advising that I "learn a course in ..."  Moreover, the down vote has no merit according to the OP as communicated to you.  And your refusal to listen to the OP and to my explanation continues to confound me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $f(z)=\frac{\sin(z)}{z}$ has a removable discontinuity and is analytic in the complex plane.  As such, it is integrable on any smooth contour $C$.

While $f(x)$ has no anti-derivative in terms of elementary functions, the integral

$$F(a,b)=\int_a^b \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx$$

exists for any real-valued $a$ and $b$.

In fact, we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx =\pi$$

The Fourier Transform of the sinc function, is given by

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}e^{ikx}\,dx=\begin{cases}\pi&,|k|<1\\\\0&,|k|>1\end{cases}}\tag 1$$

---

At the request of @user1952009, I thought it would be useful to present a section on the methodology used to find the Fourier Transform of the sinc function.

The Fourier Transform of $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is given by the Cauchy-Principal Value integral

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\{f\}(k)&=\text{PV}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}e^{ikx}\,dx\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{-L}^{L}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}e^{ikx}\,dx\\\\
&=\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{-L}^L \frac{\sin(x)\cos(kx)}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac12\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{-L}^L \frac{\sin((k+1)x)-\sin((k-1)x)}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac12\lim_{L\to \infty}\text{Im}\left(\int_{-L}^L \frac{e^{(k+1)x}-e^{(k-1)x}}{x}\,dx\right)\\\\
\end{align}$$

Now, we move to the complex plane and invoke Cauchy's Integral Theorem to evaluate the integral

$$\begin{align}
0&=\oint_C \frac{e^{itz}}{z}\,dz\\\\
&=\int_{\epsilon\le |x|\le L}\frac{e^{itx}}{x}\,dx+\int_{\text{sgn}(t)\pi}^{0}\frac{e^{it\epsilon e^{i\phi}}}{\epsilon e^{i\phi}}\,i\epsilon e^{i\phi}\,d\phi+\int_0^{\text{sgn}(t)\pi}\frac{e^{itL e^{i\phi}}}{L e^{i\phi}}\,iLe^{i\phi}\,d\phi
\end{align}$$

As $\epsilon\to 0^+$ and $L\to \infty$, we find that (after taking the imaginary part)

$$\lim_{(\epsilon,L)\to (0^+,\infty)}\int_{\epsilon\le |x|\le L}\frac{\sin(tx)}{x}\,dx=\pi\text{sgn}(t)$$

Thus, when $t=k\pm 1$, we have

$$\text{PV}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(tx)}{x}\,dx\right)=\begin{cases}\pi&,k>\mp 1\\\\-\pi&,k<\mp1\end{cases}$$

Therefore, we find that

$$\text{PV}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}e^{ikx}\right)=\begin{cases}\pi&,|k|<1\\\\0&,|k|>1\\\\\pi/2&,k=\pm 1\end{cases}$$

Comment: The topic is the Fourier transform, not complex analysis.. Please, read Open Ball's answer and look at the [Fourier inversion theorem on $L^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem#Square_integrable_functions) (which is what the OP *has to learn for his course on the FT*)

Comment: And compute the FT of $f(x) = 1_{|x| < 1}$

Comment: @user1952009 You're wrong.  Read the title and read the passage of the OP's embedded link.  Now stop harassing me or I'll flag your comments.  Am I clear?

Comment: Do you know the proof I mention ? And you can flag **your** comments, since the beginning I'm trying to explain you a mathematical fact : this isn't the proof we want in the context of the Fourier transform..

Answer (score 2):

Although it's not $L^1$, it's $L^2$ and we can make sense of its Fourier transform. You can find its formula using the $L^2$-inversion theorem. Hint: pick an arbitrary rectangle pulse; it is $L^1$, find its Fourier transform. You should get something close to $\sin x/x$. After a few adjustments you find your function.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it in form of a [$\mathrm{sinc}$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) whose Fourier transform is just a rectangular (brickwall) function.